# XmlJavaTypeAdapter in MobileFirst 7.1 does not work

Tags: java, jax-rs, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I am using Mobile First verison 7.1. I have simple adapter which returns JSON response. Response contains date and I am using LocalDateTime for that. It is not supported by Jax-Rs, so I use XmljavaTypeAdapter.

I've created adapter for LocalDateTime and annotated getter (also tried annotating field itself) with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
public LocalDateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

For some reason this annotation is ignored.

Comment: Obviously, XmlJavaTypeAdapter is not so helpful for JSON response, You can convert it to string and include it in the JSON as string, I will try to see if there is something better than string and let you know

Comment: If you're using Jackson as the JSON provider, make sure the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider is registered and not just the JacksonJsonProvider. They are both included in the same module, but the former is the one that supports JAXB annotations.

Comment: In MobileFirst we use JacksonJaxbJsonProvider OOTB - you don't need to include this provider yourself

Comment: @YotamMadem AFAIR `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is supported by Jackson XML module. It [shows here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) as being support. Wonder why it's not working for the OP here.

Comment: Yes exactly, I've thought that @XmlJavaTypeAdapter should be supported for JSON. But it seems that it is working only I directly use Jackson annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, actually it is using Jackson. I've created Jackson serializer and annotated type with this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime date;
```